# hi i need to get a sum of rows , group by with supplier and item name mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sum, window-functions

my database will be like

```
id|item_name|item_qty|added_by
1 |panadol  |200     |1
2 |panadol  |300     |2
3 |panadol  |100     |1
4 |biner    |100     |1
```

I need the output should be like

```
id|item_name|item_qty|added_by|total
1 |panadol  |300     |1       |600
2 |panadol  |300     |2       |600
3 |biner    |100     |1       |100
```

I need total of product available as well as total of each supplier regarding each product

```
Medicine:"Panadol",
1(supplier ID):300,
2(suppID):300,
Sum:600

Medicine:"biner",
1(supplier ID):100,
Sum:100
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aggregation and window functions - if you are running MySQL 8.0:

```
select
    item_name,
    sum(item_qty) item_qty,
    added_by,
    sum(sum(item_qty)) over(partition by item_name) total
from mytable
group by item_name, added_by
```

In earlier versions, you can `join` two aggregate queries, or use a correlated subquery:

```
select
    item_name,
    sum(item_qty) item_qty,
    added_by,
    (select sum(t1.item_qty) from mytable t1 where t1.item_name = t.item_name) total
from mytable t
group by item_name, added_by
```